# What SAP HANA is forked from?

Tags: hana

I am investigating SQL optimization techniques. Sometimes it is DB specific. Do you know if Hana is forked from some other DB engine?

I web searched, but nothing found about.

What it would be most similar in terms of query optimizations.

Comment: HANA was built from the ground up.  However, SAP did buy Sybase prior to HANA existence. https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/15/why-did-sap-buy-sybase/  Query optimizations   To my knowledge the HANA engine determines which [engine](https://sapstudent.com/hana/different-engines-in-sap-hana) it uses based on the SQL involved.  As far as optimizations you need to be lookign at plan viz for each SQL statement and determining what's best based on it.  Now; are we talkinga bout graphical views or SQL script? SAP themsevles have indicated moving away from Attribute/Analytical views to all Calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HANA is a in memory data base and it was built from ground up. of course there are similarities to other dbms since all can work with sql. however, HANA has a completely different technical background and is much faster than classical dbms since it operates in memory. Furthermore, HANA supports SQLScript. SQLScript is fully compatible with sql but adds a lot of features like imperative logic and much more.

Answer (score 1):

It's my observation that most of syntax and shared blocking row regime says that HANA is similar to Oracle DB

Comment: Any prooflinks?

Comment: Anyway I would appreciate any reference.